# How to pass data(structure) as a message to a thread.

Tags: c, winapi, message-queue

How do I pass data to a thread from main application?

Inside the main application I created a thread for processing error messages. While processing data in the main application if there is an error, it generates an error message and fills it into a structure. This error message(structure) needs to be passed to the thread which will then process it further and the main application should continue its work. I am trying to do this in C on windows platform.

There will be only one thread running in my application. At the moment I have defined a global variable structure (myData) and I am passing that using  **PostThreadMessage.**

```
struct myData errorData;
```

From the main application post a message using

```
PostThreadMessage(ErrorLogId, THRD_MESSAGE_EXIT , 0 , (LPARAM)&errorData);
```

In the thread I have

```
MsgReturn = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, THRD_MESSAGE_SOMEWORK, THRD_MESSAGE_EXIT);
```

At the moment it is working fine. But if processing of error message takes more time, by that time main application might get new errors and update data in global structure errorData.

I could use locking mechanism but I cannot stop main application till the thread has finished processing. How do I pass data without having it as a global variable?

Answer (score 2):

You might like to create a new instance of `struct myData` each time you are about to call `PostThreadMessage()`.

The thread needs to `free()` this instance of `struct myData` when done with it.

Adding synchronization to your current approach would be against the asynchronous concept of spawning workers while the main task continues.

Anyway the threads still need to use synchronisation on their side in case of writing something to a shared log file for example.

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to dynamically allocate a `struct myData` (using `malloc()`) each time, populate it and pass it to the thread for processing. The thread is responsible for `free()`ing it once it has completed processing it.

This approach removes any synchronization between threads on the global object `errorData` (as it is no longer required).

Answer (score 1):

How about allocating the error message dynamically (with `malloc()`), filling it and passing a pointer to it to the thread in a message? Then the thread would work with the message and deallocate it (with `free()`).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Didn't realize there was a message queue already, sorry, well then a dynamically allocated message will do of course.

**Old answer for reference:**

If you don't wish to wait until the thread finishes processing the error message, then you should use a *synchronized queue* for communications between the main thread and the worker thread. This is some pseudo code to explain what I mean:

**Worker Thread:**

```
while (queue_is_empty())
  wait;
lock(queue);
process_error(read(queue));
unlock(queue);
```

**Main Thread:**

```
if (error)
  lock(queue)
  write(queue, error)
  unlock(queue)
  //possibly signal thread
```

You don't have to implement that from scratch, you could use something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)